# 10th bullet in list in Xcode Playground with markdown is rendered as 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground

I writing the following markdown for an Xcode playground:

```
/*:
 ### Challenges

 Write the following functions:

 1. `func mapIntsToInts(array: [Int], transform: (Int) -> Int) -> [Int]` that applies the `transform` closure on each element in the input `array`
 2. `func mapIntsToStrings(array: [Int], transform: (Int) -> String) -> [String]` that applies the `transform` closure on each element in the input `array`
 3. `func filterInts(array: [Int], isIncluded: (Int) -> Bool) -> [Int]` that only keeps those elements from the input `array` for which `isIncluded` is `true`
 4. `func filterStrings(array: [String], isIncluded: (String) -> Bool) -> [String]` that only keeps those elements from the input `array` for which `isIncluded` is `true`
 5. `func reduceIntsToInt(array: [Int], initial: Int, combine: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int` that reduces all the elements in the input `array` to one single output element of type `Int` by applying the `combine` function to each intermediate result and the current value in the input `array`
 6. `func reduceStringsToStrings(array: [String], initial: String, combine: (String, String) -> String) -> String` that reduces all the elements in the input `array` to one single output element of type `String` by applying the `combine` function to each intermediate result and the current value in the input `array`
 7. `func map<T, U>(array: [T], transform: (T) -> U) -> [U]` that applies the `transform` closure on each element in the input `array`
 8. `func filter<T>(array: [T], isIncluded: (T) -> Bool) -> [T]` that only keeps those elements from the input `array` for which `isIncluded` is `true`
 9. `func reduce<T, U>(array: [T], initial: U, combine: (U, T) -> U) -> U`
 10. **recursive** versions of `map`, `filter` and `reduce` 
 */
```

In the rendered version, the 10th bullet is displayed with the number `1`. How can I make it render as `10`?

[image]